# select() api returns positive value but when reading from searial port tiggers error

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I am working on serial port application on Linux , when select () api is checked for data on waiting handles it returns positive value once data arrives on port but read() api call returns -1 , how can this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what man pages say about `select`:

> select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file
>   descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become
>   "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). **A file
>   descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the
>   corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.**

If there is an error condition on a file descriptor (RST segment received for a network sockets, for example), the only way to notify the process that is currently blocked in `select` is to make this descriptor ready for IO. The subsequent read/write function will return an error so that the application can handle it.

This behavior looks compliant with what `select` promises - flag a descriptor as ready if you can perform a *non-blocking* IO on it (however, there are some cases with network sockets, when a descriptor is flagged as ready for read, but the subsequent read operation blocks). You don't block on read - an error is returned immediately.

As for the return status of `select`, it should only return the number of "ready events" for the file descriptors in all sets. It can be negative if select itself fails (interrupted by a system call, for example - `errno == EINTR`), but not when some errors on the descriptors being watched occur.